# List comprehension for a list of lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

ok, so I have a list of lists

```
list = [['a','b','c'], ['1','2','3'], ['x','y','z']]
```

and I want to edit the first item of each list so it has a symbol before it. A "?" in this example. I figure I can use list comprehension to do this. Something similar to this:

```
list = ['?'+x for x in i[0] for i in list]
```

But that just gives me an error. This list comprehension stuff confuses me, how do I do it?

Comment: Don't name your list `list`, it masks the built-in type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do

```
l = [['?' + i[0]] + i[1:] for i in l]    (l is the list you pass in)
```

Comment: Let me reiterate again: Do not name a variable `list`; you are masking the built-in type by doing so.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Ok I heard you. I just wasn't aware there was a built in list. What does it do?

Comment: @Nathan It returns a list object.

Comment: @Nathan: [`list()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) is the type that the `[]` literal builds. You can use its constructor to turn other sequences into a list, such as `list(some_tuple)` or `list(some_string)`, or turn an iterable into a list, like `list(some_file_object)`.

Comment: You may also need to use `list` for `isinstance` checks, since it's the name of the list type.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, don't name a variable `list`; you are now masking the [built-in `list()` type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list), and can easily lead to bugs if you expect `list()` to still be that type elsewhere in your code.

To prepend a string to the first element of each nested list, use a simple list comprehension:

```
outerlist = [['?' + sub[0]] + sub[1:] for sub in outerlist]
```

This builds a new list from the nested list, by concatenating a one-element list with the first element altered, plus the remainder of the sublist.

Demo:

```
>>> outerlist = [['a','b','c'], ['1','2','3'], ['x','y','z']]
>>> [['?' + sub[0]] + sub[1:] for sub in outerlist]
[['?a', 'b', 'c'], ['?1', '2', '3'], ['?x', 'y', 'z']]
```

Comment: wait, that doesn't work... that just gives me 'outerlist' is not defined. And if i replace outerlist with list nothing changes

Comment: @Nathan: I used a different name, to not mask the built-in. The sample code didn't re-assign the result; use `outerlist = [...]` to assign it.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [['?' + el if i==0 else el for i,el in enumerate(subl)] for subl in L]
[['?a', 'b', 'c'], ['?1', '2', '3'], ['?x', 'y', 'z']]
```

Also, if you expect to modify initial list, you can modify it inplace without creating a new one:

```
>>> for sublist in L:
    sublist[0] = '?' + sublist[0]   
>>> L
[['?a', 'b', 'c'], ['?1', '2', '3'], ['?x', 'y', 'z']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
>>> l = [['a','b','c'], ['1','2','3'], ['x','y','z']]
>>> [["?"+a,b,c] for [a,b,c] in l]
[['?a', 'b', 'c'], ['?1', '2', '3'], ['?x', 'y', 'z']]
>>>
```